# Bishul Akum: now what?

Tags: halacha, cooking-bishul, bishul-akum

What is the kashrus status of a pot if the food cooked in it was Kosher, but cooked by Non Jew? Is the pot kosher or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **שולחן ערוך יורה דעה הלכות תערובות סימן קיג:טז**
>
> ‏כלים שבשל בהם העובד כוכבים
> לפנינו דברים שיש בהם משום בישולי עובדי כוכבים, צריכים הכשר. ויש
> אומרים שאינם צריכים. ואף לדברי המצריכים הכשר, אם הוא כלי חרס
> מגעילו שלש פעמים, ודיו, מפני שאין לאיסור זה עיקר מדאורייתא.‏

My rough translation:

Dishes that a non-Jew cooked food with (in our presence) that are problematic because of *bishul acu"m* are required to be *kashered*. Some say that they do not. And even according to those who require it, if it was an earthenware vessel [which would normally not be *kasherable*], you can do *hag'ala* 3 times and it will be enough [to make it *kosher*], because this issue [of *bishul acu"m*] is not a Torah-level prohibition.

But of course, CYLOR for a practicable *din*.

Comment: For something related to this from Hacham Ovadia, and what I found greatly interesting-see Livyat Hen #52.

Comment: If you look at this Inyan, he is Matir what Maran is Oser! I really recommend it, I spent a lot of time on that piece.

Comment: gavriel what is he matir? the sefardic kid in  the askenazi and or restaurant yeshiva relying on the pilot versus direct cooking?

Answer (score 8):

The Shulchan Aruch ([YD 113:16](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9732&st=&pgnum=11)) quotes two opinions on the matter, but his language (סתם ויש אומרים הלכה כסתם) seems to indicate that he sides the first opinion, namely that the vessels do require kashering. However, he notes that since Bishul Akum is a rabbinic prohibition, we allow you to kasher some things that you normally could not kasher, such as earthenware. CYLOR for specific cases.