# Food Stringencies and Dishes

Tags: kashrut-kosher, stringency-chumrah

May one eat who avoids certain foods as a stringency (eg. foods which aren't Chalav Yisroel, Pas Yisroel, and Bishul Yisroel) use plates and/or cutlery that are otherwise kosher but have been used in the past with those foods which he avoids?

Comment: This is a valid question, but I think the answer really depends on your own stringency of these matters, in general. I.e. - if you are already stringent in following these rules daily, in your home, in a restaurant, the answer as it aplies to you may be more stringent than someone who does not usually follow these rules. I would ask a rav about this.

Comment: Dovid, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please take a look at our [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) for new users and [this Help article](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on questions we can handle here. Note that we cannot provide personal advice like your rabbi can.

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14569/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't think so, this is asking about eating off plates when accepted kulot?

Comment: As far as Cholov Yisrael it would probably depend if you keep it as a chumra or as a halacha. For example, my children, who keep chalav yisrael, eat at our house on our dishes with no problem (because it is a chumra for them). The family who keep bais yosef shchita (as a chumra) also have no problem eating out our house from our pots. They have used our pots to cook their meat. On the other hand, if you kept these as halacha, then our pots would be treif for you.

Comment: @DoubleAA, looks like it, for the _bishul akum_ part.

Answer (score 1):

If something is not Bishul Yisroel but needs to be it is not Kosher, and Kashering is required.

I am not aware of any opinion that says that Pas Yisroel requires Kashering, even those who, based on the Arizal, are very strict about it.

Assuming the non-Cholov Yisroel here is what is popularly called "Cholov Stam" - that is standard supermarket available milk in a first world country - this is a whole discussion with various opinions. Among Chassidim who keep Cholov Yisroel they often insist on Kashering.

That being said, the tone of this question seems like you need to read [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi). You are asking random people on the internet for advice you yourself are calling "VERY IMPORTANT" - think about that for a second.

Comment: very good point

Comment: Are you referring to Pat Paltar or even Pat Baal haBayit?

Comment: @doubleaa, Although I suppose you could, I haven't heard of Pas Yisroel being instead of Pas Baal Habais. But of course I am referring to Pat Paltar.

Comment: @Yishai <light bulb> We should just call it Chalav Paltar.

Comment: @DoubleAA _chalav chalban_ or something, I guess. Doesn't _palter_ mean "baker"?